# 2011 Ford Fusion Heater Issue

Tags: ford, heater, heat, fusion

The battery went dead 2 days ago.  After a jump start I began my drive to work.  I initially noticed heat and then heard a sound as if my blower motor turned up to 11 (it was already at max at this point) and cold air started blowing.  Turned off the car, let sit for one minute, then restarted it.  Heat for 1-2 minutes and then the same behavior as described above occurs. Reproducible without fail.  Also noticing some trouble switching between blower modes.  For example I will have on defrost/floor and press dash/floor and the light on the button will come on but no change in where the air is blowing from.

Comment: You probably need to have the actuators recalibrated at a dealer or a shop with an equivalent tool. Try doing, key on engine off, set the tempurature all the way to cold then to hot, then cycle key and start.